# How does Serene Grace work with Razor Fang?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I plan to raise a Togekiss with Serene Grace. Togekiss can learn Air Slash which has a 30% chance of making the opponent flinch. I read from Serebii that Serene Grace doubles the chance of the secondary effect occuring, which would make the flinch chance 60%. If I make the Togekiss hold a Razor Fang, which increases flinch chance by 11.7%, will the chance of flinching become 71.7%? Or is Razor Fang's flinching buff also doubled by Serene Grace, making the overall flinch rate 83.4%?

Comment: I can't find anything about generation 6, but in generation 5 King's Rock/Razor Fang didn't increase the chance of moves which already caused flinching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Serene_Grace_%28Ability%29):

> Serene Grace boosts the 10% flinch chance due to *King's Rock* or *Razor Fang* to 20%.

But as *Studoku* commented, in generation 5 [Razor Fang](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolution-inducing_held_item#Razor_Fang) increased the chance of causing the target Pokémon to flinch when using a move that deals damage and **does not already have a chance to flinch**.

It's reasonable to think this has not changed in generation 6.